# Cannot Post error - node.js - uploading image using multer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, multer

index.html arrives on the browser by clicking a link called 'spons' from the home page "localhost:9000/" and the url changes to "localhost:9000/spons" , now when i submlit the form , it goes to the url "localhost:9000/spons/uploads" and gives "cannot POST /spons/uploads" , the images folder is in the same directory as the server.js file , can you please help me with this and suggest a solution ?

this is the index.html file

```html
<form name='uploadform' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action='/spons/uploads'>
<input name='imageupload' type='file'>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

this is the server.js file

```js
var express = require('express');
var multer= require('multer');

var upload= multer({dest:'/images'}).single('imageupload');


var router = express.Router();
router.post('/spons/uploads', upload, function(req,res){
  res.end('uploaded');
   }
 );

express().listen(9000);
```

Comment: attached router to application ?

Comment: i didn't get you sir , i'm new to node.js , can you please explain what is that about , ?

Answer (score 0):

You were getting `cannot POST /spons/uploads`, because you did not attach `router` to the app.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var multer= require('multer');

var upload= multer({dest:'/images'}).single('imageupload');

var router = express.Router();
router.post('/spons/uploads', upload, function(req,res){
   res.end('uploaded');
});

app.use('/',router); // this line is the key. 

app.listen(9000);
```

Hopes, it helps.

Comment: may i know ,why you did this change ?

Comment: `app.use('/',router);`  attaches router to app.

Comment: actually this router is being written as exports.module = router at the end , in the original code , do u think that is effecting the code ? i edited the code , but actually , this file is being imported to another main server.js file

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need explicit router, check the sample below

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var multer= require('multer');

var upload= multer({dest:'/images'}).single('imageupload');

app.post('/spons/uploads', upload, function(req,res){
   res.end('uploaded');
});

app.listen(9000);
```

Comment: i had to add this code to a large code , which used routers explicitly , so even i had to use , i don't know , i'm allowed to change to app , could you please tell what was wrong with this code ?

Comment: That's the problem, your code looks ok, and should work, try to simplify code-base, make a little example for yourself, get in touch with multer first, then add it to big project

Comment: try little demo, working demo, to be sure your environment is ok (node.version, multer.version, express.version etc)